# Trying curl in Windows to download latest avvdat-xxxxx.zip file

Tags: windows, curl

I am trying to automate downloading the latest McAfee DAT ZIP file from their repo using curl on a Windows server.  The "avvdat-xxxxx.zip" file obviously changes every day.  The actual current file as of today is "**avvdat-10352.zip**."  The file name increments every day.  As an example, I can download this in a roundabout way by running something like this:

```
curl -L -x "http://myproxyserver:80" "https://update.nai.com/products/commonupdater/avvdat-103[50-53].zip" -O
```

Obviously I would make the [50-53] range much larger to allow this work over a longer period of time.  The code above is just an example for the sake of brevity.

While this *does* download the intended zip file, it also creates a small 10-byte ZIP for the other files that it cannot find.  For instance, the above curl command creates these 4 files:

avvdat-10350.zip  (10 bytes)

avvdat-10351.zip  (10 bytes)

avvdat-10352.zip  (110,665,596 bytes)

avvdat-10353.zip  (10 bytes)

Is there any way to use curl such that it doesn't generate those small files?  Or, is there a better to way to do this altogether?  This would be pretty simple in a Linux bash script, but I'm not nearly as fluent with Windows batch/powershell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an HTML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s "https://update.nai.com/products/commonupdater/" -e "//pre/a/@href[matches(.,'avvdat-.*\.zip')]"
avvdat-10355.zip

xidel -s "https://update.nai.com/products/commonupdater/" -f "//pre/a/@href[matches(.,'avvdat-.*\.zip')]" --download .
```

The 2nd command downloads *'avvdat-10355.zip'* to the current dir.